# Unspent Bitcoins

Tags: bitcoind, unconfirmed-transactions

Is there any method to retrieve bitcoins holded in unspentable transactions?

I'm trying to transact coins from address A to address B, but coins in address A is holded in unspentable transactions. I have used "**listunspent**" command to confirm this. Now how can i retrieve the coins and transact to address B.

Is this possible or the transaction can be processed only if the confirmation reaches 100 blocks?

Somebody help me please..

Comment: This may be a language confusion.  "Unspent" refers to transactions that *have not* been spent.  "Unspendable" (note spelling) would refer to transactions that *cannot* be spent.  The `listunspent` command should list transactions that have not yet been spent, but still can be.  If you are having trouble spending them, there may be some other issue, but you would need to give more details about what is going on.

Comment: Sorry for the language confusion. If am going to spend those coins (means transact the coins), the command "sendtoaddress" was freezes, can't able to transact coins.

The unspent coins are 0.009 BTC. How to spent the coins and transact to another address?

There is no overpay fee also.